# $p:(E,e_0) \to (B,b_0)$ be a covering map ; is the induced homomorphism between the first singular homology groups injective?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, covering-spaces

Let $p:(E,e_0) \to (B,b_0)$ be a covering map ; then I know that the induced homomorphism  between first fundamental groups $\pi_1(p) :\pi_1(E,e_0) \to \pi_1(B,b_0)$ is a monomorphism . My question is , is the induced homomorphism between first singular homology groups $H_1(f) : H_1(E) \to H_1(B)$ a monomorphism i.e. injective ?

Answer (score 1):

We can set up any group monomorphism $H\to G$ as this map of fundamental
groups. So all we need is that the Abelianisation $H^{ab}$ of $H$
doesn't embed in $G^{ab}$. But that is easy to arrange. Take $G^{ab}$
as a non-Abelian simple group, $A_5$, say, and $H$ any nontrivial
cyclic subgroup.

ADDED IN EDIT

In retrospect that example looks rather extravagant. One could use
$G=S_3$ and $H=Z_3$. If one has a space $X$ with fundamental group
$S_3$ and nice enough to have a universal covering space, then it has
a double cover $Y$. The fundamental group of $Y$ is $Z_3$ embedding
in $S_3$, the fundamental group of $X$. But the first homology groups
of $X$ and $Y$ are $Z_2$ and $Z_3$ respectively.

Comment: So it need not be injective ?

Comment: that's right...

Comment: How can you view any group monomorphism as being induced from a covering map ? Does this also  mean that any group can be realized as a first fundamental group ?

Comment: Every group is a fundamental group of a $2$-complex. These are nice enough to have universal covering spaces. The classification of covering spaces does the rest.